# Sharing app setting between two web projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two separate solutions with web projects. I need to use one app setting in both. I don't want to duplicate this value in two web.config files - want to store it in one place (and **not in machine.config!**). These two web projects have other different appSettings and their web.config files are completely different.

Is it some way to share somehow just one appSetting between two web projects?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638163/how-to-include-a-config-file-for-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8818/Using-the-File-attribute-of-the-appSettings-elemen)

explains how you can refer to another config file for some of the settings. The config file doesn't have to be stored in the same folder as your web.config file so you can share it with other projects.