# How to read values from multiple Configuration file in c# within a single project?

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files, config, configurationmanager

Here in my project I have two application configuration files called `app.config` and `accessLevel.config`.  Now using the `OpenExeConfiguration` I was able to access the `app.config.exe file` but not the `accessLevel.config`.  Please help on this.

The main reason I have 2 config files is to show the difference and make the code simple.
I need to read the values from the `accessLevel.config` in my `C#` code.

Tried the below code but no use:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
config.AppSettings.File = "App2.config";
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638163/how-to-include-a-config-file-for-net).

Put this in your `App.config`:

```xml
<appSettings file="accessLevel.config"/>
```

And then have another file called `accessLevel.config` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="TestSetting" value="TestValue"/>
</appSettings>
```

And then you can access your config values in code like this:

```ccharp
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestSetting"];
```

Make sure that `accessLevel.config` is set to copy to the output directory (right click the file in Visual Studio -> Properties -> Copy To Output Directory -> Copy if Newer).

Comment: Should I have this line in `app.config.exe`?

Comment: Have edited and fixed up - see if you can get that working? Is it appSettings you are trying to move into another file, or some other config section? Either way, the same principle applies.

Comment: @Aniket Done.  sorry, I missed to pick it on the right time.

Comment: Please note that the second config (_accessLevel.config_) begins with `<appSettings />` element, not default `<configuration />` element. I spend about 10 minut before i realize this ;)

Comment: How is this  "reading values from multiple Configuration files"?
Only values from accessLevel.config are read, via app.config...

Comment: Because there are 2 (multiple) configuration files involved, as you identified. This was the solution to the OP’s question, allowing them to keep the accessLevel config in its own file, but read its values as if they came from app.config.